# Как сделать подсказку "Забыли пароль" в Андроид?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Делаю верстку страницы регистрации для приложения под Андроид. Для полей ввода логина и пароля использую EditText. Хочу сделать так, чтобы на поле ввода пароля была надпись "Забыли пароль?", как это обычно делается.Есть ли какое-то свойство у EditText'a для такой вещи? Просто рядом с EditText разместить TextView не вариант.
Вот это я хочу сделать:
[image: "Забыли пароль?" в EditText]

Comment: Поместите `EditText` и `TextView` внутрь `FrameLayout` или `RalativeLayout` и размещайте один внутри другого.

Comment: туториал на русском http://java-help.ru/edittext-floating-labels-in-android/